# How to start solving a linear system of first order differential equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

In class we modeled a car suspension as shown in the picture. I didn't include the way we modeled it because I don't think's important here, I just wrote down the state space equations. So the idea is that a car get's on a road that is on a higher level than the previous one (0.28m higher, therefore the input **u** of the system is 0.28).

So we wrote this in matlab and solved it using ode23, but I would really like to know how this is solved by hand.

My guess is that first we calculate $x_4$, then with that value we get $x_3$, $x_2$ and $x_1$. From there we recalculate $x_4$ and then the loop continues. I tried doing this but I'm not getting the correct values, so now I'm not sure if my method is incorrect or I'm integrating incorrectly. I would appreciate some help.

[image]

Comment: Linear Algebra. You can let $x$ be the vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$, and write $\dot x=Ax+b$ for an appropriate constant matrix $A$ and constant vector $b$, and then express the solution in terms of eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$. A good Linear Algebra text will show you how.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that there is this special way of solving linear systems of differential equations. Thank you, I will look into it